# When importing a CSV of invoices into Quickbooks online, how can I set the Invoice Date Format and Item Amount Tax?

Tags: date-format, quickbooks-online, csv-import

I regularly create a CSV file of invoices to import into Quickbooks online. However, every single time I do this import I have to manually set the date format of the Invoice Date column, and manually choose Inclusive of Tax or Exclusive of Tax against the column Item Amount.

Is there a way to specify within the CSV the format of these fields?

[image: Quickbooks Online CSV Importer]